# Obtaining a Y/N response from the keyboard

Tags: rust

I would like to ask the user to respond to a question with Y or N. Basically, I have no idea what I'm doing, but here's my attempt anyway

```
fn ask_confirm(question: &str) -> bool {
    println!("{}",question);
    loop {
        match std::io::stdin().read_u8().map(|x| x as char) {
            Ok('y') | Ok('Y') => return true,
            Ok('n') | Ok('N') => return false,
            Ok(_) => println!("y/n only please."),
            Err(e) => ()
        }
    }
}
```

This causes an infinite loop. The Err(e) reads "unknown error (OS Error 8 (FormatMessageW() returned error 15105))" on Win 7. Input isn't recognized regardless.

Comment: What version of Rust are you using? If you are using version 0.9, this maybe fixed on the master branch. You can [experiment using the (newly released) nightly builds](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2014-March/009223.html). (If you're using master, then... this might be a bug. :( )

Comment: I'm using a nightly build of 0.10 installed on March 28. I think my code is flawed, what's the proper way to write this function?

Comment: FYI, this is working fine for me with latest Rust from tip on Linux. So I'd suggest filing a bug.

Comment: I filed a bug report as requested.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a `read_u8` method. I used the logic I answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549784/is-it-possible-to-read-characters-from-iostdin-without-caching-input-line/32550420#32550420). Unlike in the previous question since you know that you only want Y, or N this method should work without worry. however input like `\sy` where `\s` is space will cause this method to fail.

```
fn ask_confirm(question: &str) -> bool {
    println!("{}",question);
    loop {
        let mut input = [0];
        let _ = std::io::stdin().read(&mut input);
        match input[0] as char {
            'y' | 'Y' => return true,
            'n' | 'N' => return false,
            _ => println!("y/n only please."),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, when this question was written (one and a half year ago!), Rust did have `read_uX`/`read_iX` method. Now they are provided in external crates, like `byteorder`.